# Qt MySQL - Creating New Table

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I am new to QT programming so I am trying simple MySQL operations (Connecting, Building Database, Building table ...)

I used c# till now, so here I used similar construction (i.e. I put pushButton to run code and print out messages in editText arrea)

My "Connecting" code works perfectly, so does the "Building Database" code,
but I have trouble creating the table.

1. My Working environment:

   - Win 7
   - QT Creator 3.4.1
   - Based on Qt 5.4.2
   - MySQL @ XAMPP v1.8.3

My Code:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");

    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("myTestDB");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("");

    if(db.open())  { ui->textBox->append("Connected..."); db.close(); }
    else ui->textBox->append(db.lastError().text());

    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable (id INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, firstname VARCHAR(30), lastname VARCHAR(30))" );
    if(query.exec())
    {
        ui->textBox->append("Table created");
    }
    else
    {
        ui->textBox->append("Error");
        ui->textBox->append("MySQL error:" + query.lastError().text());
        ui->textBox->append("MySQL error code:"+ QString::number(query.lastError().number()));
    }
}
```

When I run code I get this response:
Connected...
Error
MySQL error: 
MySQL error code:-1

So MySQL error is empty, and MySQL error code is -1
I also run SQL code directly to check for query errors
Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Comment: You open the database, then close it right away, then construct a `QSqlQuery` instance that doesn't refer to any database at all. What effect do you expect this sequence to have?

Comment: This question should be closed since it is a simple typo. Neither the question nor its answer is likely to help anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You close the database directly after connecting to it.

And you need to hand the `db` over to the query.

Change

```
if(db.open())  { ui->textBox->append("Connected..."); db.close(); }

QSqlQuery query;
```

to

```
if(db.open())  { ui->textBox->append("Connected..."); }

QSqlQuery query(db);
```

and then close the DB after the query.

It's your first question: Welcome to StackOverflow ;)

Comment: Thanks **Jens A. Koch** for such quick reply - **IT WORKED**. I was just copy-pasting that portion of code, and that is a very bad habit of mine. I just want to add that I didn't change this part **QSqlQuery query();** because this way Qt assumed default connection.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Yes, you are right about `QSqlQuery query;`. It will fallback to the default connection of the application. Happy hacking...